# Reading SAS based software output (TEXT files only, NOT SAS 7bdat files) into R

Tags: r, file-io, sas

I have received data which is the output of a proprietary tool written on top of SAS. I don't have access to the tool, only to the outputs. I think it runs on some version of Windows. It is, in practice, not possible to get access to the underlying SAS datasets, nor to get SAS 7bdat datasets output.

Each dataset (there are many) comes as a single directory with 6 files in it. Each file has a .txt extension, and is more or less a plain text file, with two Unicode characters at the start (BOM) "\xff\xfe". These files are named

- "STUDYNAME_SAS_Category.txt" - SAS variable value labels
- "STUDYNAME_SAS_Data.txt" - Raw data (tab or comma separated available)
- "STUDYNAME_SAS_Format.txt" - Date formats only
- "STUDYNAME_SAS_Label.txt" - SAS variable (i.e. column) labels
- "STUDYNAME_SAS_QLU.txt" - Relates, in some way to underlying questionnaire structure
- "STUDYNAME_SAS_Type.txt"  - SAS datatypes $13., 2., ddmmyy10., and so on

I can, and have, begun to write code to read these into R, but this is a lot of work.
Any suggestions or tools for reading them into R? What I would like is a pointer to a tool that knows this unusual structure, and can do something with it.

All help gratefully received.

Comment: If you can share the name of the proprietary tool that created these files, you might have better luck with someone recognizing it. Is it https://rmctu.royalmarsden.nhs.uk/macro/Help/MACRO4Help.htm#DEDR/dedr_about.htm ? It looks like that application does support other output formats.  This looks like what they've designed as export to SAS.

Comment: From the file names it looks you just need to read the files that describe the variables and use it to generate the R function call to read the text file with the data.

Comment: Thank you both - I'll check the name of the application - I do know it, but the email is on another PC. I'm working through reading the files in R, but it's quite a slow task to write and check the code!

Comment: The application is called eCRF.  The code was easier to write than I thought, and is here - https://github.com/stainesa/Geronte_Read - but needs a lot of  checking yet.